# How to post image from asp.net to the media in wordpress

Tags: c#, asp.net, wordpress, asp.net-core, wordpress-rest-api

I have a question about how I can upload image from `asp.net` api to the media in `wordpress`.

Or is that possible?

Thank you very much.

I tried to use rest api pluign but I could not found any useful link to help me.

Comment: Does your `wordpress` site  accept external request from other API endpoint?

Comment: How can I check that?

Comment: You can create an API or endpoint at your wordpress app which would be accepting the request you would send from your asp.net web api.